# Regular expression to extract part of a work

Tags: java, regex

I have a word like blahROOT. How I can extract blah in java using regular expression. I have many words which are ending in ROOT .I just want tot extract the first word.

Comment: If you just want to remove the word then why not do this: `str.replace("ROOT","");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
([\w\d\s]+)ROOT
```

Something like this should work:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\w\\d\\s]+)ROOT");
Matcher m = p.matcher(mystr);
String word = null;
if (m.find()) word = m.group(0);
```

Comment: group(0) is the entire pattern including ROOT, group(1) would be correct.

Answer (score 3):

```
String blah = "blahROOT".substring(0, "blahROOT".indexOf("ROOT"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you have to use a regular expression for this?

If your words are all ending on ROOT you could do this:

```
String s = "blahROOT";
s.substring(0, s.length() - "ROOT".length());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a string like `"blahROOT fooROOT barROOTS"`, and you want to extract `blah` and `foo` but not `bar` (since it ends in ROOT**S**), try this expression: `(\w+)ROOT\b`. Note that it matches any part before `ROOT` if the word ends with `ROOT` exactly (hence the `\b`).

Then use something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)ROOT\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher("blahROOT fooROOT barROOTS");

while (m.find()) { //loop through all matches
 String part = m.group(1); //the word parts you look for, note that group 0 represents the entire match
}
```